# Arel and pgAdmin return different data from same query with condition on timestamp

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, timezone, arel, postgresql-9.1

This is the most puzzling problem I ran into with PostgreSQL 9.1 and Rails 3.0.7. I am running Postgres and Rails 3 on the same Ubuntu 10.04 vbox guest:

```
"PostgreSQL 9.1.3 on i686-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc-4.4.real (Ubuntu 4.4.3-4ubuntu5) 4.4.3, 32-bit"
```

May app needs to run a simple query based on created_at timestamp falls on a single day based on server's timezone. In my case,  Eastern Time. I have tried different variation of "with time zone"  and  "at time zone" and got it working fine in pgAdmin,  but not in Rails web site.

Here is the class method with ARel query.

```
def self.transactions2(business_id, begin_date, end_date )
trans = LogVouchers.select( %{
      created_at
  } ).
where( %{
     created_at >= ( TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE ? at time zone 'utc')::timestamp
    and created_at < (TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE ? at time zone 'utc')::timestamp
  },
     begin_date,
    end_date  )

end
```

Here is  the controller code:

```
  def voucher_transactions
    default_date = Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day

    @end_date = params[:end_date].blank? ? \
      Date.new(default_date.year, default_date.month,  default_date.day )  : \
        Date.new(params[:end_date][:year].to_i, params[:end_date][:month].to_i, \
        params[:end_date][:day].to_i)

    @begin_date = params[:begin_date].blank? ? \
      Date.new(default_date.year, default_date.month,  default_date.day )   : \
        @begin_date = Date.new(params[:begin_date][:year].to_i, \
        params[:begin_date][:month].to_i, params[:begin_date][:day].to_i)

    @data2  = LogVouchers.transactions2(business_id, @begin_date, @end_date + 1.day)
    ...
    end
```

Here is the actual SQL code  and debug inspection  in the rails log file:

```
      LogVouchers Load (0.7ms)  SELECT 
 created_at
 FROM "log_vouchers" WHERE (
 created_at >= ( TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE '2012-04-28' at time zone 'utc')::timestamp
 and created_at < (TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE '2012-04-29' at time zone 'utc')::timestamp
 )

  ### 2012-05-01 21:18:04 -0400  voucher_transactions() @data2 =[
  #<LogVouchers created_at: "2012-04-28 03:14:29">
, #<LogVouchers created_at: "2012-04-28 03:15:24">
, #<LogVouchers created_at: "2012-04-28 03:18:19">
, #<LogVouchers created_at: "2012-04-28 03:38:35">
, #<LogVouchers created_at: "2012-04-28 03:58:08">
, #<LogVouchers created_at: "2012-04-28 15:44:46">
, #<LogVouchers created_at: "2012-04-28 17:12:20">
, #<LogVouchers created_at: "2012-04-28 18:46:45">
, #<LogVouchers created_at: "2012-04-28 18:55:47">
, #<LogVouchers created_at: "2012-04-28 18:57:52">
, #<LogVouchers created_at: "2012-04-28 19:02:15">
, #<LogVouchers created_at: "2012-04-28 19:02:50">
, #<LogVouchers created_at: "2012-04-28 19:46:36">
, #<LogVouchers created_at: "2012-04-28 19:47:17">
, #<LogVouchers created_at: "2012-04-28 19:50:22">
, #<LogVouchers created_at: "2012-04-28 19:50:56">]
```

However, if I run the SQL code directly on a query window of pgAdmin, I got correct result:

```
"2012-04-28 15:44:46.641305"
"2012-04-28 17:12:20.615641"
"2012-04-28 18:46:45.277561"
"2012-04-28 18:55:47.40109"
"2012-04-28 18:57:52.616501"
"2012-04-28 19:02:15.542964"
"2012-04-28 19:02:50.888847"
"2012-04-28 19:46:36.16556"
"2012-04-28 19:47:17.084047"
"2012-04-28 19:50:22.672805"
"2012-04-28 19:50:56.376571"
```

Note that those 5 records with created_at around  "2012-04-28 03:14:29" at UTC  is not in the correct result set.

Now the most puzzling question:
How can Rails send the same SQL statement to Postgres database and get a different result?

I am obviously missing something here. Can any guru help out?

#### Additional Notes 2012-5-2

Background: The rails 3.0 by default generated  created_at  column in all db table as "timestamp without time zone" in Postgres. I need to run a daily report based on the time zone of my server, 'America/New York'.  Due to number of tables involved, I used ARel select method to join multiple tables and passed in begin_date  and end_date timestamps. I have difficulty to get correct result set returned. It should return records with UTC timestamps:

```
2012-04-28 04:00:00    to   2012-04-29 04:00:00
```

but it returned records with UTC timestamps:

```
2012-04-28 00:00:00    to   2012-04-29 00:00:00
```

What I can figured out is to change the class method:

```
def self.transactions2(business_id, begin_date, end_date )

st_tz_offset      =   Time.zone.now.formatted_offset(true)
st_begin_date_tz  =   "#{begin_date} 00:00:00#{st_tz_offset}"
st_end_date_tz    =   "#{end_date} 00:00:00#{st_tz_offset}"

trans = LogVouchers.select( %{
      created_at
  } ).
where( %{
     created_at >= ( TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE ? at time zone 'utc')
    and created_at < (TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE ? at time zone 'utc')
  },
     st_begin_date_tz  ,
    st_end_date_tz  )

end
```

Which in fact, tells Postgres to translate that `timestamp with time zone` into `timestamp without time zone` before comparing. And that worked for me. I know this is too complicated. I would very much appreciate someone pointing out a better way to achieve this.

#### Additional Note 2

- If possible, I would avoid changing default setting in Ubuntu/Linux server, Postgres server as it tends to cause other side effects.
- In the future,  these daily cutoff timestamps are based on the `TimeZone` setting of `current_user` instead of the `TimeZone` of server. Because users of same web app can be spanned over multiple time zones and the daily report has to make sense to respective logged in user.

Comment: Which timezone settings you have on the machine with pgAdmin and on the server?

Comment: @vyegorov  pgAdmin, pgSql server, rails app are all reside on same ubuntu server ( my dev machine).  postgresql.conf  file's timezone is set to be default to server.   ubuntu's timezone setting is  "america/new york".    Rails' app.config.timezone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your expression depends on the local time setting. This:

```
SET  timezone = 'EST';
SELECT TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE '2012-04-29' AT TIME ZONE 'UTC';
```

returns a different timestamp than this:

```
SET  timezone = '-2';
SELECT TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE '2012-04-29' AT TIME ZONE 'UTC';
```

Obviously, you have a different time setting in the connection from pgAdmin than you have in the connection from ARel. Find out with:

```
SHOW timezone;
```

`timezone` is defined in `postgresql.conf`, but can be set to a different value at any time. You can reset it to the default with:

```
RESET timezone;
```

I explained the PostgreSQL handling of timestamps and [time zones in more detail in this recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9576170/939860).
More about [time zones in the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-TIMEZONES).

---

If you want "midnight at UTC", use this expression instead:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP '2012-04-29' AT TIME ZONE 'UTC';
```

Or simply:

```
SELECT '2012-04-29 0:0 +0'::timestamptz;
```

This returns the same internal value regardless of the `timezone` setting. It will displayed according to the local timezone, though. So with EST, you will see:

```
2012-04-28 19:00:00-05
```

---

#### Without time zone

According to your additional info, your table holds data of the type `timestamp without time zone` -  or simply `timestamp`, as the default is `without time zone`. And these timestamps are implicitly based on `EST`.

If you want to retrieve data for one day, starting at midnight, ending at midnight, **independent of the time zone** you are currently in, do not use the data type `timestamp with time zone` (or `timestamptz`) at all. Just use `timestamp` and everything is groovy. The server should get:

```
WHERE created_at >= timestamp '2012-04-28 0:0'
AND   created_at <  timestamp '2012-04-29 0:0'
```

Or:

```
WHERE created_at >= '2012-04-28 0:0'::timestamp
AND   created_at <  '2012-04-29 0:0'::timestamp
```

Or even just:

```
WHERE created_at >= '2012-04-28 0:0'
AND   created_at <  '2012-04-29 0:0'
```

If you want a different slice of the data **depending at your current time zone**, then the server should get this:

```
WHERE created_at >= '2012-04-28 0:0'::timestamptz AT TIME ZONE 'EST'
AND   created_at <  '2012-04-29 0:0'::timestamptz AT TIME ZONE 'EST'
```

The term `'2012-04-28 0:0'::timestamptz AT TIME ZONE 'EST'` calculates the time in New York (without time zone) when it is midnight locally.

Or you can calculate the timestamps in your app accordingly and use the above query without time zone.

Comment: many thanks for such rapid response. Your other post helped me a lot to get to a point to ask somewhat intelligent question as posted above.  With this post, I think I am getting closer. You confirmed my suspicion of a config issue because same sql return different from two diff sqlClient:  RailsArel vs  pgAdmin.  I checked  pgAdmin    's SHOW timezone: <pre> "localtime" </pre>    My Rails 3.0.7 app's config is  <pre>      config.time_zone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'  </pre>  I will dig deeper into  postgresql manual page you provided and see if I can figure out something there.

Comment: The fix I found without messing with all the default settings on pgSql or Rails is to be explicit about the timezone info of datetime string.  So  the sql statement should be: <pre> SELECT 
 created_at
 FROM "log_vouchers" WHERE (
 created_at >= ( TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE '2012-04-28 00:00:00-04:00' at time zone 'utc')
 and created_at < (TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE '2012-04-29 00:00:00-04:00' at time zone 'utc')
 )
</pre>  So in Rails code,  I need to do the following:

Comment: <pre>     st_tz_offset =   Time.zone.now.formatted_offset(true)
    st_begin_date_tz  =   "#{begin_date} 00:00:00#{st_tz_offset}"
    st_end_date_tz    =   "#{end_date} 00:00:00#{st_tz_offset}" </pre>

Comment: @GeorgeW: Your fix seems more complex than necessary. If your question stated what you want to achieve exactly, I could be more specific. What exactly is in your table and what should the WHERE clause filter?

Comment: I agreed with you. I have updated my original post to be more specific.  I added additional codes for controller method: voucher_transactions  to help illustrate objective.   In additional, I added more notes to explain my objective better.  There might be a more standard "Rails" way to do this.  Hope you can point out a better, cleaner solution. I look forward to your illuminating post.

Comment: @GeorgeW: Added a bit to my answer.

Comment: I am much obliged to your generosity in illuminating me in such thorough, detailed and timely manner. I voted up and chose your answer. You certainly led me to the right spot in addition to the right direction to solve my problem. The critical stumbling block is the difference between timestamp  and timestamptz  concepts in pgSql. You did a great job highlighting the difference. Thank you!

Comment: @GeorgeW: I bow to your kind words, Sir, and share your delight that it works now.